# how to solve spring boot start issue?

Tags: spring, spring-boot

> root project> 0% CONFIGURING [2s]assLoader

```
 .   ____          _            __ _ _ to the maintainers of org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \able warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \ll be denied in a future release
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v2.0.6.RELEASE)

2018-10-27 17:45:35.485  INFO 116 --- [  restartedMain] com.musicapp.api.ApiApplication          : Starting ApiApplication on DESKTOP-FS4FN9F with PID 116 (C:\Users\User\Documents\BurchApp\api\build\classes\java\main started by User in C:\Users\User\Documents\BurchApp\api)
2018-10-27 17:45:35.485  INFO 116 --- [  restartedMain] com.musicapp.api.ApiApplication          : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2018-10-27 17:45:35.597  INFO 116 --- [  restartedMain] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Refreshing org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.AnnotationConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext@7b441fd0: startup date [Sat Oct 27 17:45:35 CEST 2018]; root of context hierarchy
WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by org.springframework.cglib.core.ReflectUtils$1 (file:/C:/Users/User/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework/spring-core/5.0.10.RELEASE/cb270a60ceb573961588f511222984de64b4bc96/spring-core-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar) to method java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(java.lang.String,byte[],int,int,java.security.ProtectionDomain)
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of org.springframework.cglib.core.ReflectUtils$1
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
2018-10-27 17:45:37.677  INFO 116 --- [  restartedMain] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration' of type [org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$57f070c] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2018-10-27 17:45:38.523  INFO 116 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8843 (http)
2018-10-27 17:45:38.562  INFO 116 --- [  restartedMain] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2018-10-27 17:45:38.563  INFO 116 --- [  restartedMain] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.5.34
2018-10-27 17:45:38.575  INFO 116 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.a.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener   : The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: [C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11.0.1\bin;C:\WINDOWS\Sun\Java\bin;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3;C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Library\mingw-w64\bin;C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Library\usr\bin;C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Library\bin;C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Scripts;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\system32;%M2_HOME%\bin;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11.0.1\;C:\Program Files\Apache Software Founddation\apache-maven-3.5.4\bin;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\Gradle\gradle-4.10.2\bin;C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\Scripts\;C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\;C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code\bin;C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\GitHubDesktop\bin;C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\npm;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11.0.1\;;.]
2018-10-27 17:45:38.747  INFO 116 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2018-10-27 17:45:38.747  INFO 116 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 3169 ms
2018-10-27 17:45:38.855  INFO 116 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.ServletRegistrationBean  : Servlet dispatcherServlet mapped to [/]
2018-10-27 17:45:38.855  INFO 116 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.ServletRegistrationBean  : Servlet webServlet mapped to [/h2-console/*]
2018-10-27 17:45:38.861  INFO 116 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'characterEncodingFilter' to: [/*]
2018-10-27 17:45:38.862  INFO 116 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'hiddenHttpMethodFilter' to: [/*]
2018-10-27 17:45:38.862  INFO 116 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'httpPutFormContentFilter' to: [/*]
2018-10-27 17:45:38.862  INFO 116 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'requestContextFilter' to: [/*]
2018-10-27 17:45:38.987  INFO 116 --- [  restartedMain] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
2018-10-27 17:45:39.237  INFO 116 --- [  restartedMain] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Start completed.
2018-10-27 17:45:39.256  INFO 116 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.jdbc.datasource.init.ScriptUtils     : Executing SQL script from class path resource [schema-h2.sql]
2018-10-27 17:45:39.294  INFO 116 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.jdbc.datasource.init.ScriptUtils     : Executed SQL script from class path resource [schema-h2.sql] in 38 ms.
2018-10-27 17:45:39.296  INFO 116 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.jdbc.datasource.init.ScriptUtils     : Executing SQL script from class path resource [data-h2.sql]
2018-10-27 17:45:39.305  INFO 116 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.jdbc.datasource.init.ScriptUtils     : Executed SQL script from class path resource [data-h2.sql] in 9 ms.
2018-10-27 17:45:39.471  INFO 116 --- [  restartedMain] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Building JPA container EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2018-10-27 17:45:39.508  INFO 116 --- [  restartedMain] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [
        name: default
        ...]
2018-10-27 17:45:39.611  INFO 116 --- [  restartedMain] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate Core {5.2.17.Final}
2018-10-27 17:45:39.627  INFO 116 --- [  restartedMain] org.hibernate.cfg.Environment            : HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
2018-10-27 17:45:39.633  WARN 116 --- [  restartedMain] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/JAXBException
2018-10-27 17:45:39.648  WARN 116 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.f.support.DisposableBeanAdapter    : Invocation of destroy method failed on bean with name 'inMemoryDatabaseShutdownExecutor': org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Database is already closed (to disable automatic closing at VM shutdown, add ";DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE" to the db URL) [90121-197]
2018-10-27 17:45:39.649  INFO 116 --- [  restartedMain] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown initiated...
2018-10-27 17:45:39.655  INFO 116 --- [  restartedMain] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown completed.
2018-10-27 17:45:39.661  INFO 116 --- [  restartedMain] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]
2018-10-27 17:45:39.687  INFO 116 --- [  restartedMain] ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener :

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2018-10-27 17:45:39.695 ERROR 116 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/JAXBException
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1694) ~[spring-beans-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar:5.0.10.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:573) ~[spring-beans-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar:5.0.10.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:495) ~[spring-beans-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar:5.0.10.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:317) ~[spring-beans-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar:5.0.10.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar:5.0.10.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:315) ~[spring-beans-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar:5.0.10.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar:5.0.10.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1087) ~[spring-context-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar:5.0.10.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:857) ~[spring-context-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar:5.0.10.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:548) ~[spring-context-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar:5.0.10.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:140) ~[spring-boot-2.0.6.RELEASE.jar:2.0.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:754) ~[spring-boot-2.0.6.RELEASE.jar:2.0.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:386) ~[spring-boot-2.0.6.RELEASE.jar:2.0.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:307) ~[spring-boot-2.0.6.RELEASE.jar:2.0.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1242) ~[spring-boot-2.0.6.RELEASE.jar:2.0.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1230) ~[spring-boot-2.0.6.RELEASE.jar:2.0.6.RELEASE]
        at com.musicapp.api.ApiApplication.main(ApiApplication.java:10) ~[main/:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49) ~[spring-boot-devtools-2.0.6.RELEASE.jar:2.0.6.RELEASE]
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/JAXBException
        at org.hibernate.boot.spi.XmlMappingBinderAccess.<init>(XmlMappingBinderAccess.java:43) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
        at org.hibernate.boot.MetadataSources.<init>(MetadataSources.java:87) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
        at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.<init>(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:209) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
        at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.<init>(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:164) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:51) ~[spring-orm-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar:5.0.10.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:365) ~[spring-orm-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar:5.0.10.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:390) ~[spring-orm-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar:5.0.10.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:377) ~[spring-orm-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar:5.0.10.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:341) ~[spring-orm-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar:5.0.10.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1753) ~[spring-beans-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar:5.0.10.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1690) ~[spring-beans-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar:5.0.10.RELEASE]
        ... 21 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.xml.bind.JAXBException
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:583) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521) ~[na:na]
        ... 32 common frames omitted
```

BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 17s
3 actionable tasks: 2 executed, 1 up-to-date

Comment: Please add your pom.xml .

Comment: I am using gradle

Comment: Well in that case please add your gradle conf. I want to see what jars you are importing

Comment: You are missing a JAX dependency.

Comment: It looks like you may be using Java 11. If so, please note that Spring Boot 2.0 does not support Java 11. It will be supported by Spring Boot 2.1 which will be released next week.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your build.gradle file , add dependency for javax.xml.bind

compile 'javax.xml.bind:jaxb-api:2.3.0'